# python - processing very large files (>90GB)

Tags: python, file, buffer

I need to process a couple of very large files (>90GB each). Only a small portion of the files are important for me. I want to scan through the files and write the necessary lines to another file, so I don't need to process such large files every time I run an experiment. Every line is about 1000 characters.

I use the following code:

```
def readFile(inputFile, outputFile):
    startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('10/06/2010 00:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('10/13/2010 23:59:59', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

    total_lines = 0

    with open(inputFile, 'r') as a_file:
        for a_line in a_file:   

            total_lines += 1

            id, date, content = splitLine(a_line)

            datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

            if (datetime_object > startDate and datetime_object < endDate):
                appendToFile(outputFile, a_line)

    return total_lines

def splitLine(long_string):
    values = long_string.split(",")
    return values[0],values[1],values[2]

def appendToFile(outputFile, outputString):
    try:
        file = open(outputFile, 'a+')
        file.write(outputString)
        file.close()
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Error writing to file: " + outputFile)
    return
```

The problem is, every time I run the script, the process gets stuck around 10.000.000th line. When I use `htop` command, I can see that Python only uses around 8GB of RAM when it gets stuck, and the virtual memory used keeps increasing and then the OS kills the process after a while.

I used different files, and also both Python 2.7 and 3.5. I also tried using `with open(inputFile, 'r', 16777216)` to use buffering but the result didn't change. I'm running the code on macOS Sierra 10.12.4 and the machine has 16GBs of RAM.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `appendToFile()` do? You should include a full example, which includes *all* the code requires to reproduce the problem ("[mcve]").

Comment: Don't post your code in comments, you can [edit] your question ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker edited :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in pieces, until you find what you want. Like this:

```
f = open('yourfile')

piece = f.read(4096)
while piece:
    # Implementation for each piece
    piece = f.read(4096)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way to do that would be to call Unix awk command from python. This will work on both Mac and unix.

You call call unix commands from python like this:

```
import os
os.popen('ls -l > result.txt')
```

Running this sample code will create a file named result.txt that contains the output of the ls -l command.

Similarly, you can scan through your files with awk and pipe the result to another file.

From the man page of awk:

> awk
>
> NAME
>         awk - pattern-directed scanning and processing language
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   awk [ -F fs ] [ -v var=value ] [ 'prog' | -f progfile ] [ file ...  ]
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION:
>
> Awk  scans  each input file for lines that match any of a set of patterns specified literally in prog or in one or more files specified as -f progfile.  With each  pattern  there  can  be  an  associated action  that  will  be performed  when  a  line of a file matches the pattern.  Each line is matched
>   against the pattern portion of every pattern-action statement; the associated action is performed for each  matched  pattern.  The file name - means the standard input.  Any file of the form var=value is treated as an assignment, not a filename, and is executed at the time it would have been opened if it were a filename.  The option -v followed by var=value is an assignment to be done before prog is executed; any number of -v options may be present.  The -F fs option defines the input  field  separator to be the regular expression fs.

Read this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76805/read-log-file-between-two-dates to see how to use awk to read log files between two dates.